# $\mathbb{Q}$-rational Point obtain Preimage in $X_{\overline{k}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

I have a question about an argument used in Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" in the excerpt below (or look up at page 132):

[image]

REMARK: The setting of 4.8.6 (e.g. the definitions of $\pi(n)$ and $\Pi(n)$ and the assumption that $P_i$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-rational) is given here:
S

[image]

Now the QUESTION:

The author says

> Since $P_i$ is rational over $\mathbb{Q}$, there is a unique point $\overline{Q_i}$ 
>   of $X_{\overline{k}}= X \times Spec(\overline{k})$ lying above $P_i$ .

By assumption on previous pages $k$ is a field of characteristic $0$.

My questions are:

1.: What is $X$ here? Seems to be assumed as an integral proper normal curve defined over
$k$ of characteristic $0$ but it's just my guess.

2.: why $P_i$ MUST here be a rational $\mathbb{Q}$-point? What could fail if $P_i$ is for example a $K$-point where $K$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$? Nevertheless there exist is a point $\overline{Q_i}$ 
of $X_{\overline{k}}$ lying above $P_i$ by pullback structure of $X_{\overline{k}}$. What problem occure here if $K \neq \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a finite type $k$-scheme. For any closed point $x\in X$ let us denote by $\mathrm{Spec}(k(x))\to X$ the map picking out that point. Note then that, by definition, you have a fibered diagram

$$\begin{matrix} X_{\overline{k}} & \to & X\\ \downarrow & & \downarrow\\ \mathrm{Spec}(\overline{k}) & \to & \mathrm{Spec}(k)\end{matrix}$$

Let $f:X_{\overline{k}}\to X$ be the natural map above. Note then that we have a natural fibered diagram

$$\begin{matrix}f^{-1}(x) & \to & \mathrm{Spec}(k(x))\\ \downarrow & & \downarrow\\ X_{\overline{k}} & \to & X\end{matrix}$$

Combining these we get a fibered diagram

$$\begin{matrix}f^{-1}(x) & \to & \mathrm{Spec}(k(x))\\ \downarrow & & \downarrow\\ \mathrm{Spec}(\overline{k}) & \to & \mathrm{Spec}(k)\end{matrix}$$

But, this means that

$$f^{-1}(x)=\mathrm{Spec}(k(x))\times_{\mathrm{Spec}(k)}\mathrm{Spec}(\overline{k})=\mathrm{Spec}(k(x)\otimes_{k}\overline{k})$$

Note then that if $k(x)/k$ is separable of degree $n$ (which is the case you're in) then $k(x)\otimes_k \overline{k}\cong \overline{k}^n$. Thus,

$$\mathrm{Spec}(k(x)\otimes_k \overline{k})\cong \mathrm{Spec}(\overline{k}^n)=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Spec}(\overline{k})$$

Thus, $f^{-1}(x)$ is a singleton if and only if $x$ is rational.

More generally, $f^{-1}(x)$ will be a singleton if and only if $k(x)/k$ is totally inseparable. Since you're in characteristic $0$, the point is that's equivalent to being trivial.

Comment: so the "neccessarity" for beeing a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point is here a red herring? It suffice just that $k(x) /k$ is algebraic (separability holds automaticalls since characteristic $0$)?

Comment: @KarlPeter Just to be sure we're on the same page here: what is $k$ here? If you said a $\mathbb{Q}$-point I strongly suspect that $k=\mathbb{Q}$! The claim then that being a $\mathbb{Q}$-point is not the red herring, it's that you're a $k$-point for whatever your base $k$ is. If $k(x)/k$ is separable of degree $n$ the above says that there are $n$ preimage points of $x$--so if you want just one preimage point you need $[k(x):k]=1$ so that $k=k(x)$.

Comment: unfortunatelly the author didn't told that explicitely but $k=\mathbb{Q}$ seems to be the only reasonable choice or  - if I understand you correctly - a $\mathbb{Q}$ in general means just a point with residual field equals base field

Comment: @KarlPeter It almost certainly means $\mathbb{Q}$ or, at least, your other interpretation (which is weird, so I hope that's not what is meant). Either way, you see that the only way (for $k$ perfect and and for closed points) you could get a unique preimage point is when it's a $k$-point.